# Resize uiscrollview after adding content programmatically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an Contentview with uielements inside Uiscrollview. Below screenshot of my storyboard:
[image]

I want to add the option for the app that if the user clicks the button it will add  label on the bottom of the contentview (below red underscored label - dzialTerminOutlet).
[image]

I'm adding the new label programmatically using following code:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

label.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
label.textColor = UIColor.black
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
label.text = "test label"
contentView.addSubview(label)


label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dzialTerminOutlet.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 85.0)
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0)
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0)
```

The scrollview does not resize though. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to activate

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dzialTerminOutlet.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
  label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 85.0),
  label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
  label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0)
])
```

2- You need to remove the bottom constraint established in IB between `dzialTerminOutlet` and `contentView` to be able to insert the new one and make the scrollView resize accordingly to avoid conflicts between it and

```
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 85.0)
```

so hook it as an outlet and deactivate it or search contentView for the bottom constraint and remove it

Comment: Your answer seems very logic to me. However after i disable the bottom contraint (dzialTerminBottomConstraint.isActive = false) the scrollview gets shorter by 85 px.

Comment: make it -85 (minus)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set scrollView contentSize with new size?
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.size.width, height: self.contentView.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way i'm using it a lot is to connect your contentView height constraint with an IBOutlet object and update it's value.

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewHeight : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And after adding your label:

```
contentViewHeight.constant += labelHeight
```

Don't forget to set the contentView constraint (top, bottom, leading, trailing) = 0 with scroll view